# Qt5-default package not found

Tags: server, qt, vim

I am trying to do:

```
sudo apt-get installl qt5-default
Reading package list... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: unable to locate package qt5-default
```

On a [Qt-forum](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36677) I found out I could try to add something like this to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main
```

But I can't save it when I am done adding the line. I did while I am in the right directory:

```
sudo vim sources.list
# and I also tried 'vi'
```

I am trying to this on Ubuntu Server 12.04. I was able to update the qmake version on my laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. So what I would like know is how can I upgrade my qmake from 4 to 5. And how do I exit and save such files as I mentioned? I tried `[ESC]` + `:` + `q` + `[ENTER]`

---

**Edit 1** 
I have now successfully edited the `sources.list` file. But now after doing `sudo apt-get update`. 
 I get the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://http.debian.net jessie main jessie Release: The following 
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
[16 char hexadecimal number]
```

I though maybe it isn't something critical I continued with install `qt5-default`, but that didn't seem to work either, because I a few errors which I can't reproduce. I did `qmake --version`, but that still returned:

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.1 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`
```

Answer (score 3):

To edit your sources.list you can do

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then to save click the keys `[Shift]` + `[z][z]`. If you are in insert mode, fist click `[Esc]` to exit insert mode then click `[Shift]` + `[z][z]`

That will exit and save changes.

for a full cheat-sheet go here http://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html

Also I recommend using the graphical editor gedit

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**OR**

```
sudo pico /etc/apt/sources.list
```

They are easier to use in my opinion, it is a nano derivative. To save `CTRL+X` then click `y`. It says how on the bottom

for some help with pico go here: http://accc.uic.edu/service/shell-accounts/pico

**MAKE SURE TO RUN**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after you have made changes to your sources.list file. Otherwise your local database will not be updated.

**ALSO**

If you get an error about needing to add a key then

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys THE_DISPLAYED_KEY_HERE
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: since I am working on Ubuntu Server GUI applications (such as gedit) won't work. But the `[SHIFT]` + `zz` worked :) But still the update isn't completed :(